# Laravel 5.1 How to get all models and related models by querying a related model?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1

Model Relationships...
Apartment has many Floorplan.
Apartment has many Photo.
Floorplan has many FloorplanImage.

I want to get all Apartment that have a Floorplan with 0 bedrooms.
ALSO, I want to grab the related Photo, and related FloorplanImage.

My somewhat useless code...

```
    $apartmentsWithStudios = Floorplan::with(['apartment', 'floorplanImage'])
                                        ->where('bedrooms', '=', 0)->get();
```

How do I grab the Apartment and all related models from querying the Floorplan model? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`whereHas` + `with`:

```php
Apartment::whereHas('floorplans', function ($floorplans) {
  /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Query */
  $floorplans->where('bedrooms', 0);
})

  // with all floorplans and their images
  ->with('photo', 'floorplans.floorplanImage')

  // OR with floorplans without bedrooms and their images
  ->with(['phooto', 'floorplans' => function ($floorplans) {
     $floorplans->where('bedrooms', 0);
  }, 'floorplans.floorplanImage'])

  ->get();
```

Comment: Missing closing ] with second with.  Other than that, code is exactly what I needed.